# Asp .net Web api how to avoid url hit from browser?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Am using web api 1. For Get apis i can enter the url (servername:portno/api/Controllername/apiname/) in the browser address bar and call the api directly from browser and get the json output

This seems to be a security issue. How can I restrict this url hit?

But I can not be using any authentication or authorization in the web api as its handled from UI side (mobility)

Comment: why can't you use authentication or authorization for web api's? How do think the verbs are secured?

Comment: securing a web service from the UI side only is not actually secure. Noone stops someone else to just have a look at the requests from your UI application and, as you found out, replicate them from a browser or some other application. You can try checking for some specific header field as a sort of authentication but that could easily be discovered by a third person.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways how to secure your Web API. And actually you don't need some "HTML UI" to do them.

- You can have either HTML UI where your user will HTTP POST form and will exchange login/password to some token (session id, OAuth single sign-on token etc.).
- You can HTTP POST form without user as well, just from your code. And result will be the same, credentials are exchanged to some tokens, which are included in each next requests in HTTP headers
- You can programatically restrict access to your API from some IP adresses or services

Anyway all the ways are require to implement authentication and/or authorization techniques. And what you see in HTML UI is only top of the iceberg and can be done without user.

When you need to close HTTP requests from browser just check HTTP header with browser agent.

Either [authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) or just special handler for browser agent HTTP header, you will require at least MessageHandlers for both.

Your URL to start deep dive into WebAPI authentication http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security

Comment: One more information is we have cors implemented using web.config like below <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="somedomainname"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

Comment: But still I can hit the get api using IE. since the request from IE does not contain origin this is not working out.  Is there a way to fix this problem without going for authentication and all. Also we use only web api 1 so advanced cors concepts wont work.